# HERE.com Routing API: cannot calculate routing

Tags: routes, here-api

I'm using HERE.com Routing API to calculate truck path using coordinates from truck GPS tracker. So I don't need to build the optimized route or whatever but just define what the route was passed by the truck: road number, state, mileage etc.

For some reason API does not calculate routing information (returns "subtype":"NoRouteFound","details":"Error is NGEO_ERROR_GRAPH_DISCONNECTED_CHECK_OPTIONS") for the next two points (they are both in the URL below along with all another flags I used):

http://route.cit.api.here.com/routing/7.2/calculateroute.json?app_id=XXXXXXX&app_code=XXXXXXXXX&mode=fastest;carHOV;traffic:disabled;tollroad:-2&instructionformat=text&routeAttributes=waypoints,summary,summaryByCountry,legs&legAttributes=length,links,summary&maneuverAttributes=position,length,link,roadName,nextRoadName,roadNumber,nextRoadNumber,direction&linkAttributes=length,flags,roadNumber,roadName,nextLink&waypoint0=geo!42.90279,-78.89738&waypoint1=geo!42.90847,-78.91348

Using HERE.com map service I see there valid roads on the map. Some comments or suggestions about this?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there is an issue with the `mode` you are using. I guess that there is a road from point A to point B - which is flagged as both a **toll road** and an **HOV route**. The combination of toll-free and HOV route leaves no available roads out of the area.

If you get a failure like this, try relaxing the constraint (HOV + strict exclude toll):
e.g. instead of `mode=fastest;carHOV;traffic:disabled;tollroad:-2`  use one of the following:

- Car + strict exclude toll - `mode=fastest;car;traffic:disabled;tollroad:-2`
- HOV Car + dislike toll - `mode=fastest;carHOV;traffic:disabled;tollroad:-1`